# How to change SVG icon color on select in ToggleButton

Tags: reactjs, svg, material-ui, styled-components, togglebutton

I have in my project 4 ButtonGroup from MUI, where each of them have SVG Icon and children as name of button. Although background of button and name works once selected, but SVG icon remains all the time the same color. How to make it work and SVG Icon will also change color on select ?

Below is the example how it's built:

```
 <StyledToggleButtonGroup
                            color="warning"
                            value={alignment}
                            exclusive
                            onChange={handleAlignment}
                        >
                            <StyledToggleButton
                                aria-label={DetailsTranslation}
                                onClick={() => handleGoToDetails()}
                                value={Routes.TrainsDetails.path}
                                aria-pressed="true"
                            >
                                <StyledDetailsIcon />
                                {DetailsTranslation}
                            </StyledToggleButton>
                            <StyledToggleButton
                                aria-label={LinesTranslation}
                                onClick={() => handleGoToLines()}
                                value={Routes.TrainsDetailsLines.path}
                            >
                                <StyledLinesIcon />
                                {LinesTranslation}
                            </StyledToggleButton>
                            <StyledToggleButton
                                aria-label={WheelsTranslation}
                                onClick={() => handleGoToWheels()}
                                value={Routes.TrainsDetailsWheels.path}
                            >
                                <StyledWheelIcon />
                                {WheelsTranslation}
                            </StyledToggleButton>
                            <StyledToggleButton
                                aria-label={ServiceTranslation}
                                onClick={() => handleGoToService()}
                                value={Routes.TrainsDetailsService.path}
                            >
                                <StyledServiceIcon />
                                {ServiceTranslation}
                            </StyledToggleButton>
                        </StyledToggleButtonGroup>
                    </TrainsDetailsToolbarWrapper>
```

and the styles for first button:

```
 export const StyledToggleButton = styled(ToggleButton)`
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Poppins;
        margin: 0.5rem;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1.5rem;
        border-radius: 0.4rem;
        border: none;
    `;
    export const StyledDetailsIcon = styled(MenuIcon)`
        margin-right: 1.3rem;
    `;
```

this is definition of MenuIcon, of of the used icons

```
/// <reference types="react" />
/// <reference types="react-dom" />

declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  export const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
    React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string }
  >;

  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.bmp' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.gif' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.jpg' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.jpeg' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.png' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.webp' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the list of component states and their associated class names [here](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#state-classes).

```
const StyledToggleButton = styled(ToggleButton)`
  &.Mui-selected {
    color: red;
    background-color: pink;
    /* Put your styles to apply in selected state here */
  }
`;
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: not working, I believe once SVG icon is inside there must be something added

Comment: @marcinb1986 can you add the icon definition in your question?

Comment: thats Icon definition, hope it's what You are asking :

import { MenuIcon, LinesIcon, WheelIcon, ServisIcon } from '@nevomo/shared';

export const StyledDetailsIcon = styled(MenuIcon)`
    margin-right: 1.3rem;
`;

Comment: @marcinb1986 No, I want to see the `MenuIcon` definition, not its wrapper.

Comment: I have edited the post, hope it's this one You are asking

Comment: @marcinb1986 I still don't see the `MenuIcon` definition anywhere in your question though. I need to see the svg file to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry, it's this one <svg width="16" height="20" viewBox="0 0 16 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M4 14H12V16H4V14ZM4 10H12V12H4V10ZM10 0H2C0.9 0 0 0.9 0 2V18C0 19.1 0.89 20 1.99 20H14C15.1 20 16 19.1 16 18V6L10 0ZM14 18H2V2H9V7H14V18Z" fill="black"/>
</svg>
what is not working is toggling of the color once ToggleButton is selected. I know how to change the color, but it doesn't toggle color depending on whether it's selected or not

Answer (score 2):

There's [a `selected` class](https://mui.com/api/toggle-button/) in `ToggleButton` that can be overridden using styled, `sx` prop, or via global theme override.

```
export const StyledToggleButton = styled(ToggleButton)`
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Poppins;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  border: none;
  &.Mui-selected .MuiSvgIcon-root {
    color: red;
  }
`;

export const StyledDetailsIcon = styled(MenuIcon)`
  margin-right: 1.3rem;
  color: blue;
`;
```

this is the class which is added to ToggleButton when I inspect it
[image]

Comment: not working unfortunatelly

Comment: can you please provide a codesandbox with reproduction of the issue, it will be very helpful

Comment: I just added to main question the class which is added to ToggleButton. Maybe it will help